# Crear una matriz de matrices usando punteros c++

Tags: c++

Buenas noches. Hace años estudie C y actualmente estoy utilizandolo pero ya con C++ para introducirme en las clases llegado su momento. Desgraciadamente no tengo mis apuntes (de C) y las consultas que he metido en google no me satisfacen ademas las pruebas que estoy haciendo no salen tanto que ya no tengo un codigo ni siquiera que compile

Mi idea es factible, se que lo es porque me suena haberlo hecho en el pasado, tengo una serie de vectores cuatro vectores y supongamos de dimension dos.

a=(a1,a2)
b=(b1,b2)
c=(c1,c2)
d=(d1,d2)

Y por otra parte tengo la capacidad de crear una matriz de 2x2

z=(z1,z2;z3,z4)

La idea es que z1 almacene la memoria de a en primer lugar, es decir, z1 tenga la posicion de a, concretamente del primer componente.

Posteriormente cuando ya tenga esa matriz llena de punteros le haria mas operaciones.

El esbozo que les dejo y he probado es:

```
float a[2]={1,2};
float z[2][2];
float *puntero=NULL; //Puntero nulo
puntero=a //Apunto al vector a concretamente a la posicion 1 (0 en c/c++)
z[0][0]=&puntero //Le doy al primer componente de la matriz la direccion de memoria de puntero que es la del vector.
```

¿Que hago mal?

Answer (score 1):

Bueno desde el momento que C++ no soporta un array de referencias lo mas simple es recurrir a un array de punteros, en tu caso declaras un arreglo de punteros de 4 posiciones y acada posicion le asignas un array de enteros.

```
int main()
{

    int a[]={1,2};
    int b[]={3,4};
    int c[]={5,6};
    int d[]={7,8};


    int *arrayPunteros[4]={a,b,c,d};

    //Muestra las direcciones de memoria de cada array
    cout<<a<<endl;
    cout<<b<<endl;
    cout<<c<<endl;
    cout<<d<<endl;

    //Recorremos el array para comprobar que realmente coinciden las direcciones 
    // ademas mostramos su contenido
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
        cout<<"Direccion de arrayPunteros["<<i+1<<"] "<<arrayPunteros[i]<<endl;
        cout<<"Valor ==> "<<arrayPunteros[i][0]<<endl;
        cout<<"Valor ==> "<<arrayPunteros[i][1]<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Sabia que se podia pero no habia leido en ningun lado que no se pudiera hacer el array que contuviese punteros. Sobre el codigo me surge una duda ¿Por que se muestra la direccion de memoria sin el operador &?